# Minor interface bug: question titles not getting underlined if single line

Tags: bug, status-declined

I'm using `IE8` on `XP SP3`.

If you go to the [list of questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) and hover the cursor over a question title that only takes one line on the screen, it will not get underlined, as a link would.

But if the title spans across multiple lines, it will get underlined with little red dots as soon as you hover the mouse over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, weird -- reproduced, but I'm chalking this little cosmetic issue up to IE being generally strange and praying IE9 fixes it :)

Comment: Oh well :) Status-decline [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64209/minor-interface-bug-se-question-titles-not-getting-underlined-if-single-line) as well then :) Hmmm... Verbing does weirds language :)